# Why can't we vote on answers in /review?

Tags: support, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is voting removed from new review system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system)

Whilst going through the 'new' style "Low Quality Posts" on Stackoverflow's */review*  section, I noticed that voting on the answer you're reviewing is not available.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263094/is-openid-a-flawed-concept/11196657#11196657) to the question "Is OpenID a flawed concept?" isn't a particularly good answer.

However, none of the review options really cover it in my opinion:

- **Looks Good** - no, it doesn't look good, it's a poor answer
- **Edit** - no, not without radically changing the answer
- **Recommend Deletion** - just because it's poor, doesn't mean we need to completely remove it
- **Not Sure** - no, I *am* sure that it's a poor answer that should be downvoted

What's the thinking behind disabling the downvoting during Reviewing? After all, I could just  navigate out of */review* and downvote it anyway?

Comment: @AnnaLear - I agree that this is now a duplicate - but surely the *other* question is the real duplicate, as it was asked a day after this question?

Comment: Technically, yes, but the other question was converted into a feature request and seems to be getting more attention. I felt it would be a disservice to the overall point to close it as a dupe instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think that going out of /review and downvote (or upvote) **is** the good solution, as it ensures you have a complete view of the question, comments and answers (which usually give some light to the question).

Downvoting direcly may make you miss the comment which explain/justify the question (or its last edited version).

Even to just decide between the standard options ("Looks Good", etc.) I often open the question normally in order to be sure I have a clear vision. And, as I often feel I'm not experienced enough in SO to decide to close an answer, I frequently just downvote and let old SO users decide if it should be closed.