# Why is voting removed from new review system?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, review

In the old review system we could vote for posts while reviewing. We were able to upvote great posts and downvote bad quality posts:

[image]

But in the new review system we are not able to vote on posts:

[image]

Voting is one of the main components of SE communities. While surfing or reviewing posts I am eager to vote on them.

There are some related responses about voting in [New Feature: Community Review Tasks - Now in Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta):

1. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139545/178505
2. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139789/178505
3. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139551/178505
4. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139680/178505

So why is voting removed from new review system? Should it be added back?

EDIT: I've turned this into a feature request, since in reviewing a post on SO I saw one that I didn't feel should be deleted, but the author would need to improve it, so I had no option to select.  I thought it needed a downvote in it's current form, but had to click into the question to do that.  Please put the voting back on the review page. - [Lance Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13295/lance-roberts)

Comment: Isn't the point of reviewing to either delete or improve the answer? If so, why would you be voting? If the answer is to be deleted, voting on it would be pointless, right? You could always open the answer link in a separate browser window and vote on it there if you like.

Comment: Does review means `action delete or improve` every time ? Can't posts be good as given original? Then `delete or improve` can be done by clicking post link also. There can be other reason why not given voting in review system. I want to discuss and not argue. Everyone should know benefits of new review sytsem.

Comment: I really don't know. Only the mods could answer that. Personally I think it doesn't belong, but it could go either way.

Comment: I wouldn't mind being able to vote there. I think we should encourage users to vote more, so why not? But I can see where they're coming from, because in essence you should focus on one task, the reviewing, *not* voting.

Comment: @slhck: I agree with encouraging users to vote. But how could voting doesn't come in reviewing. Does review means there will be always bad quality posts? How voting will loose focus in review?

Comment: @JimmyPena voting still counts as a review action

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Voting is one of the main components of SE communities. While surfing or reviewing posts I am eager to vote on them.

Answering is also one of the main components. Flagging's gotten pretty big too. But neither of these are available in the current review queues.

Note that you can't close or vote to delete from the suggested edits queue either, or dispute closing in the LQ queue.

The core philosophy here is that each queue focuses on a specific task or question, and provides the tools most important for resolving it. If you want to do something else, **there will always be a prominent link to the full question page**.

A concern with allowing voting in the Low Quality queue specifically is that you're not viewing answers in the context of other answers, or a question in the context of its answers. You're never able to vote in these circumstances normally - it's worth remembering that voting directly from the list of questions was considered early on, and discarded as too likely to produce bad results.

Finally I should note that even though I'm declining this, voting *might* make sense in the future on different types of /review queues. The objections I've outlined above would have to either not apply, or be mitigated in some way though.

---

#### Update: voting allowed (and encouraged) in First Posts and Late Answers queues

Based in part on this discussion, we've enabled voting (and most other post-specific actions) in [the First Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts) and Late Answers queues. The concerns I expressed above
still apply, *however:*

- The importance of guiding new users early, and getting attention for answers that might otherwise be too easily overlooked, is important enough to justify a little bit of extra attention.
- The amount of skew enabled by this (both to post score and user reputation) is limited by the posts allowed and the attention granted them: only one post per user (for first posts), only posts from very low-rep users (<= 10 for late posts), and only one "active" review per post before dequeuing.

While I strongly encourage folks to vote in this queue, please use common sense: if you don't understand the subject of the post, just click "Not Sure" and move on.

Comment: How about allowing voting on the upcoming First Questions queue?

Comment: That's worth thinking about; First Questions (that aren't automatically tagged as LQ) probably could use things like voting and editing.

Comment: @Shog9: Similar with late answers and first answers also.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: Then you start getting into the fuzzy area where you aren't seeing it in the context of other answers. Just because it's their first answer doesn't mean you should upvote it. There are plenty of cases where people sign up and post some of the same things already provided in other answers. Shog9: I think the close votes task should allow voting. Upvoting a downvoted question which has close votes is a good way to save a question which may not be close-worthy or has been edited after those votes were received. As well, downvoting a question is a good way to get it closed faster.

Comment: @Shog9 Can we also get the vote view counts as well? It's kinda annoying to have to click through to the question to be able to see the # of up/down votes.

Comment: @Mysticial: are you talking about the voting breakout you can normally get by clicking on the current score?

Comment: @Shog9 Correct. I think I've subconsciously clicked on the number at least 5 times yesterday expecting it to expand into the vote counts. It'd be nice if it actually did expand. :)

Comment: Please let me vote while in the Close Vote review queue. It's the job of the honeypots to catch bad reviews. The CV queue is so crowded that I always filter it down to areas of my expertise anyway. Sometimes the CV queue shows me a post deserves a downvote (which may get it automatically deleted later on). And sometimes it shows me a post that deserves an upvote because it's been improved (added code, clarified question, etc).

Comment: If you have a special interest in a particular question, break out of /review and do whatever you like, @KatieK: vote, flag, answer, etc.

Comment: Do you think it would be worth reconsidering voting in the Low Quality Review given recent events? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256360/1947286

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256361/1947286

Comment: No, I do not, @apaul - and I'm not sure how either of those discussions justify such a thing. Is there a particular reason that legitimate but mediocre answers should be deleted instead of downvoted? Is there a particular reason that answers some users found helpful should be deleted based on a flag? Are you forgetting that VLQ flags deemed helpful *come with an automatic downvote?*

Comment: I was unaware of the auto-downvote. It just seems that giving reviewers the option to downvote in the queue would resolve some of the problem with unnecessary deletion.

Comment: There are much less destructive ways to reduce unnecessary deletion, @apaul34208. My primary concern is making sure the system is able to delete everything that *needs* to be removed, with a minimal amount of collateral damage.

Comment: @Shog9 - An unfortunate *feature* of the 'Downvote during review' option is that the reviewer is presumably doing a favor by reviewing and downvoting **if** a downvote is a fair assessment. A consequence of being helpful is that it costs you a point to downvote either punishing the fair reviewer or discouraging a fair review. Perhaps if a few reviewers all downvote then everyone should get their points back (except the OP), that encourages correct reviews and prevents 'free drivebys'.

Answer (score 27):

The Review page needs both Voting buttons and a button that recommends the answer be turned into a comment.  There are some posts that need more detail, but aren't wrong or bad enough to warrant deletion.  They need editing by the author so a downvote is the only appropriate option, but right now that means having to click into the question to do that.

It would also be nice when you see a good answer to be able to upvote there instead of the extra clicking around.

Comment: And the means to flag!

Answer (score 6):

**Does review mean only bad quality posts (delete or improve)? How come voting isn't enabled in reviewing?**

In my free time, I do review of posts. And there are many times I am facing many very good quality posts. Now I have to give extra click and vote for it. It will be good if voting is placed with new review system.

Also I think voting doesn't loose focus while reviewing the posts. So it shouldn't be removed.