# Why is accept rate more important for /review tasks than answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, accept-rate

In Shog9's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141145/164376) to a question about why the  voting options have been removed from the \Review task beta, he explains:

> The core philosophy here is that each queue focuses on a specific task
>   or question, and provides the tools most important for resolving it.
>   If you want to do something else, **there will always be a prominent
>   link to the full question page**.

I have for a while now been convinced that accept rates should generally be hidden or at least less prominent. (Various permutations of this idea have been suggested in other Meta threads.) So given Shog9's explanation for the absence of voting, I was suddenly struck by the fact that when reviewing questions with close votes, the asker's accept rate is shoved in my face, but I have to click through to see any answers:

[image]

I can understand the argument that questions should be evaluated on their own, independent of any answers, although personally I sometimes find it helpful to see if a question labeled as "Not A Real Question" has attracted any quality answers. So while *I* wouldn't mind having the answers included, I recognize that I may be in the minority.

However, I feel pretty strongly that **if** answers aren't essential information for evaluating close votes, then accept rate surely must be even **less** relavent, no? In that case, could accept rate please be removed from the \Review queues?

(And could this bolster the argument for it being hidden, or shown in a harder to reach place, more generally...?)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a bit of code somewhere that does nothing but render those author blocks, and it's getting re-used here. Because, yeah, accept rate has *no* relevance in that context. BTW: the big bold title of the question is also a link to the question - so it's actually linked in *two* places.

Comment: joran, as an aside, I too judge questions in review based on answers received. In fact, in [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/), Jeff quotes Aarobot, who says that some questions that seem like they're NARQ or NC actually end up getting some pretty good answers. I tend to let those slide if I come across them. While we shouldn't lower our standards for questions that don't yet have answers, I can see the value in showing answers on questions in /review. Perhaps it would even make it easier to edit and improve them...

Comment: @jmort253 Thanks! It's reassuring to hear that other experienced reviewers feel similarly.

Comment: Completed as [accept rate is no longer shown with on the usercard for a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140951).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because the accept rate is there has absolutely no bearing on it being "useful" or "essential" in your decision. Only the stuff at the right is considered helpful statistics that you should consider. The accept rate is there because it's displayed in the user box on questions. You're viewing a question (determining whether to vote to close it or not). Therefore, it's in the user box. It's really *that simple*. They're just reusing a template that already exists.

If it were to disappear from the review panel, it would more likely be due to them removing it *everywhere*, which is [currently being discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate) and is strongly supported.

Comment: I take your point, although I disagree slightly with your first sentence. It seems to me based on Shog9's answer that individual elements were specifically included/excluded from \Review based on their perceived usefulness for that task. Hence my point that as it stands now it appears that answers were deemed less important than accept rate.

Comment: I think you're reading too much into it. In the old review panel, there was a list of actions which could be completed on any post you reviewed: upvote, downvote, edit, comment, vote to close, flag, and delete. The idea is that, depending on the task, only a select few of them are relevant in "reviewing" the post properly. Anything else should be done at the post itself. The stats at the right are an added bonus to help in your decision.