# Allow comments to be flagged on all reviewable posts

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-flags, review

The new review system is awesome, and it's great that we can see comments on the posts to be reviewed. But, a lot of times, questions that end up in the close vote queue attract snarky/snide comments.

It appears we're able to flag comments on answers in the low quality posts queue, but not on questions in the close vote queue. Would it be possible to be able to flag comments there, and on any other post that currently doesn't allow it, as well?

Comment: I think we should be able to flag anything, questions, answers and comments.

Comment: We could add some friction by removing the ability to add comments in the review queue.

Comment: @bfavaretto [Recent comments from Shog9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141145/149432) indicate that it's by design you can't flag everything, but I think you should at least [be able to flag as "spam" or "doesn't belong here"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143654/149432), given those can be resolved by community review (like comments can).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this feature request has been implemented somewhere in the past. To be honest, I can't remember *not* being able to flag comments in the Close Vote review queue.

[image]

<sub>(random question & comment from the review queue, I didn't flag it)</sub>