# Allow  "spam" and "doesn't belong here" flagging in the review queues

Tags: feature-request, flags, review

In the new review queues, we're given a number of options:

- Close / Delete / Recommend Deletion
- Edit
- Do Not Close / Looks Good
- Not Sure

However, there's no option for when we find a post that's spam or offensive/gibberish/abusive.

Looking around, I saw that [Shog9 addressed the lack of full flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141145/149432) in a question about the lack of voting:

> The core philosophy here is that each queue focuses on a specific task or question, and provides the tools most important for resolving it. If you want to do something else, **there will always be a prominent link to the full question page.**

I can see that for the "needs moderator attention" flag, but not for the ones resolvable by the community:

- Close vote flags for those who can't yet vote to close
- Spam
- Doesn't belong here

I think these flags fit in with the core philosophy: community review, and resolution, of low quality posts or questions with close votes. 6 people flagging a post as "spam"/"doesn't belong here" to delete it doesn't seem to be functionally different than 5 people voting to close a question, or 3 people voting to delete an answer.

So, given that close vote and and low quality posts queues are where most of the posts falling into these categories are going to be, it seems like an oversight that we can't do this.

Comment: you can always open the question by clicking the title and reporting it as spam there.  it's a workaround but whatever