# Include the option to flag posts as spam in the Low Quality queue

Tags: feature-request, review, spam, low-quality-posts

I guess this is an additional to previous requests like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166338/answers-flagged-as-very-low-quality-should-have-the-same-tools-available-to-th) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143654/allow-spam-and-doesnt-belong-here-flagging-in-the-review-queues).

But I just came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/2651545) review item, and was unable to flag it as spam.

***edit:*** Since I posted this, the item has been removed (deleted) here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I guess you could argue that "delete" serves the same functional purpose, but I like the idea of marking spam as spam. Plus, it carries with it the special whammy of -100 reputation to the original revision owner. That gives me a warm feeling deep inside.

Comment: For egregious cases, I take the time to go to the post itself and flag from there.

Comment: @AlEverett Didn't think of doing that - but I guess that is always an option. I am just wondering why not include the option? It is available on other queues.

Comment: @AlEverett if I can't do something from the review queue, I don't do it at all 'cause I'm lazy

Comment: @the: I'm pretty lazy, too, but spam annoys me enough that I'll go out of my way to report it.

Comment: **+1** Do want this.

Comment: I just ran into a post in the LQ review queue I wanted to flag as spam. It was [an audit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5132468) (and might not make sense to <10k users), but still - I went to the extent of opening the question in order to flag it.

Comment: @CodyGray Most spammers are 1-rep users on their way to be destroyed, but there's an important reason to get rid of spam properly and not by ordinary deletion now: the spam filter trains on posts that are deleted as spam, not on posts that are deleted as LQ. I've pinged the devs about this.

Comment: Time to try again methinks. Nominal bounty added.

Comment: You should be able to flag all posts in all review queues, frankly.

Comment: Delete button has a reason “ This is a link-only answer (and not spam)”, but doesn’t have “This is a spam”

Answer (score 19):

#### Spam deserves its own special place in hell.

And the sooner it gets there, the better. It should *always* be possible to flag a post as spam — when reading it, from a review queue, preferably even from the post feed in a chat room.

But at the very least there should be an option to flag a post as spam from each and every review queue.