# Preferred action when seeing spam in VLQ review

Tags: discussion, review, spam, low-quality-posts

Currently, in the Review UI, I only have an option of "link-only answer (and *not* spam)", there's no "flag" link or anything else to mark it as spam. I have to go to the main UI to do that.

The reason I'm asking is, I regularly get spammy posts in VLQ review. Though they typically turn out to be audits, you never know. I do know, however, that by system's design, spam is intended to be dealt with in a different way than VLQ, so *just* recommending to delete looks like an improper way to handle such a case.

So, the question is:

- Is it sufficient to select "recommend deletion" in these cases? Won't this undermine the system's effectiveness in dealing with spam and spammers?

  - Since I cannot know if such a post is an audit, I'm asking for **both** cases when it is an audit **and when it is not**.

Comment: Related, but no duplicate: [Include the option to flag posts as spam in the Low Quality queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191860/255554)

Comment: I don't review anywhere there are audits so I'm not sure but I would think the whole point of audits are to make sure you're taking the correct action, so the answer in the case of an audit or not should surely be the same.

Comment: @Cai sure, I see that known-spam posts are an easy way out to fill the audits quota. But I wish to know if the designers _really thought about consequences_ when implementing this. How did they weave this into the existing anti-spam machinery?

Comment: Also asked on MSO: [What am I supposed to do with a piece of spam that I review in the low quality queue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274496)

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks. Sadly, nothing official there or anything I didn't already mention, except a link to [a "feature request" that outright criticizes the practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238647/dont-use-spam-post-as-audits-in-the-low-quality-review-queue).

Comment: Yes, I am quite disappointed with the lack of resolution on my post there.

Answer (score 5):

Practical guide to spam in review queues:

- If you are reviewing on a site **with** audits: It's probably an audit. Spam doesn't live that long on these (active) sites. Play along with the silly audit system by recommending deletion. (In the unlikely event it's not an audit, you will know by the absence of "Congratulations"; then hit "back" in the browser, go to the post and spam-flag.)
- If you are reviewing on a site **without** audits: go directly to the post and spam-flag; skip it in the Review Queue. Deletion from review queue is not a desirable outcome for spam posts (for one thing, it doesn't replace the post content with a "not shown" notice).

Comment: "for one thing, it doesn't replace the post content with a "not shown" notice" - I thought one spam flag was sufficient to trigger the notice on deletion?

Comment: No, it's not enough: but it will be fixed [next week](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272643).

Comment: That's the problem: I seriously doubt that "go directly to the post" and "playing (along with) the silly audit system" are the by-design way. _"No sane man could..."_