# Should I nominate incorrect answers for deletion?

Tags: support

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5530126/546661) in the Low Quality posts queue. It's an incorrect guess at the answer.

Should I nominate it for deletion? Is it okay to judge answers in the review queue based on technical correctness?

Answer (score 15):

**Incorrect answers should be downvoted, not removed.**

That said, the answer you link to is probably more suitable as a comment. It's a one-liner than doesn't explain anything; not really an answer.

Comment: You can help them earn their Peer Pressure badge! It's really the decent thing to do.

Comment: So on the review page should I incorrectly say that it "Looks good", or just downvote and skip it with "Not Sure"?

Comment: @PeterOlson Downvote and click "looks good", just for the irony of it ;)

Comment: You can't downvote from the review queue. Unfortunately.

Comment: @bfavaretto Do I smell a feature request?

Comment: I am not convinced I agree with keeping incorrect answers on the site; what's the rationale?

Comment: @DaveNewton Sometimes it's extremely valuable to show people what _not_ to do. Also only a very small subset of users can delete posts, we can't expect them to be able to judge the technical correctness of potentially every post on the site.

Comment: @YannisRizos While I agree it *may* be valuable to have examples of what not to do, I'd rather see SO be a collection of *right* stuff, not wrong. Users can vote to delete at some point, after a post has downvotes. AFAIC, incorrect, downvoted answers should be deleted, and that's why we have the power to vote for deletion.

Comment: @DaveNewton First thing you do when you happen upon an incorrect post is to downvote it. _If_ you can vote to delete and you think it should be removed, then by all means do so, but don't ask others to delete it for you (notice the question is about _nominating_ the answer for deletion).

Comment: @YannisRizos You mean [this feature request?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system)

Comment: I agree with Dave Newton that technically incorrect answers should be deleted. But this doesn't require flagging or any moderation intervention. Most of the time the natural process happens and the OP deletes the answer themselves after receiving a few downvotes. Now, there is a separate problem of people not downvoting nearly enough and some people even upvoting these answers.

Comment: @Esailija Exactly why technically incorrect answers should be downvoted rigorously.

Comment: Incorrect answers should definitely be removed. They tend to confuse newbies (i. e. if someone answers `you have to free() a string literal` and somebody does it, it will crash, right?)

Comment: @H2CO3 That's why we downvote them, would you seriously try something suggested in a -5 answer? But you would _certainly_ know what to avoid.