# We should be able to vote on questions from the review queue

Tags: feature-request, voting, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is voting removed from new review system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system)

On the [review pages](https://stackoverflow.com/review) it shows posts and their vote counts, but does not include the upvote/downvote buttons.

Occasionally I'll see a post that's interesting to me and want to upvote, or I'll see an unuseful post that deserves a downvote. To be able to do this, I have to click the link to the post up in a new tab and then vote. It would be a more seamless experience if I could just vote from the review page.