# Allow more actions from review

Tags: feature-request, voting, flags, review

Here is how I think we could have flagging and voting back, without compromising the philosophy behind the new review tasks:

[image: I heard you like freehand circles]

The picture shows an answer on the Low Quality Posts queue, but the question below it could have the same link, so we could also vote on it or flag it. Maybe the new link should only be available to users with a certain reputation, or who reviewed at least so many posts.

#### Advantages

- Current UI is almost unchanged until you click the new link.
- New link does not draw too much attention, and focus is maintained on the main task and its suggested actions.
- Showing the voting and flagging links still requires an additional click (good for extra tought on your actions), but doesn't require a new browser tab (ajax assumed).
- Implementation shouldn't be too difficult, since the server-side code for this actions obviously exists, and client-side code could be adapted from the old review system, the 10k flag queue, or elsewhere.

#### Disadvantages

- This was pointed out by Shog9 when he [status-declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141145/167534) a [feature-request for voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140405/167534):

  > A concern with allowing voting in the Low Quality queue specifically is that you're not viewing answers in the context of other answers, or a question in the context of its answers. You're never able to vote in these circumstances normally - it's worth remembering that voting directly from the list of questions was considered early on, and discarded as too likely to produce bad results.

  (But I think "you're never able to vote in these circumstances normally" is a little too strong; sometimes there is no need for more context, and it's not too unfrequent.)

Comment: Isn't "Current UI is almost unchanged until you click the link" more work, not less, and therefore a disadvantage to the developers?

Comment: @Robotnik More work to whom? It think it's and advantage because the UI is left uncluttered and focused.

Comment: The new review system is in beta, and we have been asked for feedback. There are other people asking for the same functionality, and I tried to consolidate multiple feature requests into one. I don't think the amount of work required should be our first concern here.

Comment: While I agree with @Shog9's objection towards allowing voting without context, even this could be resolved by expanding this feature request a bit.  Instead of just a "more/fewer actions" button, make the button show/hide the entire context of the question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see much difference for the reviewer, but I see plenty of difference for the developers. Your solution is milimeters away from

[image]

which is functionally the same. It opens in a new tab allowing you to see the question in its full context and allowing you to easily close it and go back to reviewing. I like the idea but it might be more work than it's worth.

Comment: I don't think it's that much work...

Comment: It might not be, but the point I'm making here is that although I like the idea I don't see it as important enough to add to other tasks the developers are working on.

Comment: It's a lot more convenient and user-friendly, I think, if one doesn't have to leave the review interface to do what they think is right for the good of the question/answer.  I personally hate having to open up an extra tab or go back and forth between pages, for something that could just as easily (and sensibly) be done in one interface.