# Permit downvotes in the review system

Tags: feature-request, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is voting removed from new review system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system)

We are told: If an answer is merely wrong, don't delete it. Just downvote it.

However, the review workflow does not have a button, let alone an app, for that.

As it is, it's very easy to forget about the idea of downvotes, and just shoot delete votes at wrong (or even annoying) answers. The additional work of clicking on the question, finding the answer, downvoting, returning, and clicking 'Looks Good' is a lot of clicking.

I suggest that it should.

Comment: Everything that is not directly accessible in the review system is indirectly accessible by clicking the link to get to the actual post.  Some operations were deliberately left out of the review system to provide a bit of friction; this is one of them.

Comment: But you've made what you want more frictional than what you don't want. You want downvotes, but you've made them harder than deletes.

Comment: We never "want" downvotes...they're a last resort, after all (at least, they're supposed to be).

Comment: I thought about this myself while browsing the review queue recently, but I think I agree with the current decision that leaving that extra point of 'friction' is good; I only have so many votes per day, and having it *right there* while going through the 'low quality' review queue would just make it far too easy to breeze through all my votes, too quickly. And the fact that you are reading a never-ending line of 'bad' posts could influence upcoming votes.

Comment: Check my [related feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143703/allow-more-actions-from-review) from about a week ago.