# more on review workflow: make it easier to decide that the real problem is the question

Tags: discussion, review

Bad questions breed bad answers. Using the new review facility is a constant reminder of this.

Right now, I have to spend a lot of clicks to take appropriate action in this case. I have to click on the question link, vote to close, click on back, click on 'don't care'.

More buttons?

Comment: Related to [my feature request for allowing more actions from review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143703/allow-more-actions-from-review).