# Add a downvote option in the VLQ review

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

There are many answers that are well-formed and well-formatted but are simply plain wrong or misleading. When reviewing, I often have a hard time deciding which action to take, as:

- **Looks Good**: is OK per se but I would never say "good" (would work if the wording was changed slightly),
- **Edit**: The question is formatted well and editing it to be right would go against the intent of the author,
- **Recommend deletion**: this looks like the most reasonable choice, but I wouldn't flag it if I were browsing the site in normal mode,
- **Not sure**: I am quite sure what is wrong but I end up clicking this because the other three options do not seem fitting.

My proposal is to add a fifth option - **Downvote** that would make it easier to choose in case of such answers.

Comment: related to [Why is voting removed from new review system?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system)