# Enable up/down-voting during reviews

Tags: feature-request, review, deleted-answers, low-quality-posts

This is a follow-up post of [Answer not deleted after six "Recommend Deletion"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29799/290189).  In the linked question, [an LQ review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1152968) has ended with six "Recommend Deletion".  However, the post has *not* been automatically removed from the site since it had a score of +1 throughout the review.  As a result, Prof. Carl Mummert emphasised the importance of down-voting the review target to be deleted in the comments below the accepted answer of the linked Math.Meta.SE question.  Allowing up/down-voting during review would facilitate the removal of such posts.

Update: review target deleted via votes

---

Edit in response to comments:

- [Add a downvote option in the VLQ review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144854/259305) *only suggests downvoting*, while this question *also suggests upvoting*.
- My question *also applies to Close reviews*, in which [great questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1153592) have popped up.  The linked meta question is *only about LQ reviews*.

Since @ShadowWizard has specifically mentioned LQ reviews, I would like to bring up [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1083741) in which a high-quality answer receives two "(recommend) deletions" and one downvote (viewable to 2k users) from high-rep users who don't know the field.  Upvotes can protect such answers from disappearing.

Once we see good answers, [we should upvote them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15706/259305).  That's part of the SE mechanism.  The suggestions of this post helps users to do so *without* leaving the review.

Comment: Keep in mind that an outcome of "Recommend Deletion" on positively-scored answers does raise an automatic moderator flag.

Comment: Can't see any reason to allow upvote in the VLQ review, but agree about downvotes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The linked dupe only suggests downvoting, while mine also suggests upvoting. My questions applies also to Close reviews due to [great questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1153592) popped up in the queue. Since you specifically mentioned LQ review, I would like to draw your attention to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1083741) in which a high-quality answer receives two "(recommend) deletions" and one downvote (viewable to 2k users) from high-rep users who don't know the field. Upvotes can protect such answers from disappearing.

Comment: OK, please add this to the question to make it clear and I'll reopen it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Done!

Comment: @ShadowWizard If somebody who thinks the post is low quality and should be deleted is allowed to downvote, surely somebody who thinks the post is decent and should be kept should be allowed to upvote?

Comment: @David only in First Posts review. VLQ review is only for posts that should be either deleted or left alone, but are very rarely good.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The quality of answers in LQ review depends on sites.  For example, in [math.se], many great answers written by high-rep users have fallen into this review due to the length of answer.  Upvoting them within the review is in line with SE's philosophy of selection by votes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard In a perfect world, posts that are actually good would never get flagged as low quality. But, in a perfect world, we wouldn't need a VLQ process in the first place! If you accept that not all posts in VLQ are bad enough to downvote, I don't understand why you feel that none of them can ever be good enough to upvote.