# "I'm Done" for late answers without voting

Tags: feature-request, review, late-answers

Wouldn't it make more sense to allow the "I'm Done" button without having to edit or vote up someone's late answer?

If it is an answer that resolves someone's issue but you may not find it useful, why do we have to upvote the answer to get the "I'm Done" button?

I see a possibility of someone only searching for old questions so they can add answers knowing that people reviewing the Late Answers thread will have to either upvote their post or edit it for it to leave their queue.

**Edit:** I don't want to click "Not Sure" because while some answers are good and should be added, I don't think they are good enough to get an upvote; just good enough to probably help someone should none of the other answers work for them.

[image]

Comment: This may be silly, but what is the "I'm Done" button? I don't recall ever seeing one.

Comment: @Oded it is usually greyed out.

Comment: OK, you meant on the review queue.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147867/late-answers-and-first-posts-encouraging-unnecessary-actions

Comment: Also heavily discussed in kiamlaluno answers there: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts/146991#146991 . While I completely agree with @Bot on the topic i have a feeling this will be a 'status-declined'

Comment: I wouldn't call it a workaround, but you can vote on a post, hit I'm Done, then go back to the post and rescind your vote. You still are +1 towards shiny review badges, but the post is unaffected.

Comment: Some of these same points are also discussed in [Late answers in the /review queue (#2) - marked answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148124/late-answers-in-the-review-queue-2-marked-answers). Effectively I asked for a `Looks good to me` button (or similar).

Answer (score 8):

A little less than a year after this question was asked, a "No Action Needed" button became available, to allow dismissing the review task while explicitly taking no action on it.

In this case, clicking that button is the right thing to do.

(For context to future readers: the "Not Sure" button in the question's screenshot did the same thing as today's "Skip" button.)

Comment: So a simple no-longer reproducable ;)

Comment: I don't think this applies to any other site than SO either, so this would be a remain from the pre-meta-SE days. The whole thing could be safely deleted.

Comment: @Lundin This applies to all sites, *except* Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -10):

Is the answer useful? Upvote it!
Is the answer useless? Downvote!

Why is this so hard?

Yes, I'm serious. I get your question but I don't think you are fair. Voting should not be seen as a way of dealing out reputation/karma. It is a way of tagging a question as either useful or not. If you can't decide, the question is probably either useless or you are not sure. I think this is pretty nicely put into the review workflow here.

Comment: I find all answers in C# tag useless because I don't practice C#. Should I downvote them all?

Comment: What if I don't think the answer is useful enough to deserve an upvote, nor useless enough to deserve a downvote? It's a stupid requirement.

Comment: Chichiray, of course the level of usefulness should be evaluated in terms of answering the question, not in terms of helping you. If you are not fluent enough in C# to do this evaluation chances are you are "Not Sure". NullUserException, I have added that to my answer; I see no reason to not upvote answers which you think are useful. Answers that are neither useful nor useless may not be a good answer to the question; thus, useless.

Comment: @EmilVikström That's flawed black and white thinking.

Comment: @Emil: I think you forget something very important; have a look here: [Should good answers always be upvoted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15706/) People often vote on answers *after comparing them to all the competing answers*. But in the Review Queue, you are only looking at an isolated answer. For all you know, that question already has 7 other answers that are way better; or the answer you're looking at is a copypaste of the accepted answer, so it deserves to get downvoted and deleted. Simply upvoting everything that looks okay in and of itself can be actually harmful.

Comment: False dichotomy. Sometimes a question is merely "sufficient". I don't upvote or downvote *everything I see*. I upvote things that are *good* based on some criteria of my own design. I downvote things that are *bad*. Things that are OK? They don't get votes from me. We should not be *encouraging* people to up/down vote *everything*.