# Do we need up-/downvoting options when reviewing close votes?

Tags: discussion, voting, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is voting removed from new review system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system)

When reviewing close votes you currently can *not* vote on a question. Sometimes I find myself wanting to downvote, and once in a while even upvote (if the question was improved, or well-written / researched).

I'm *not necessarily suggesting we should* have question voting in this review task. I'm just asking: what do you guys think? Would this help in warning others about bad questions (downvoting) / telling folks about good ones (upvoting), or is it better to stick to the task at hand (closing or not) without bothering about question votes?

Answer (score 3):

You can always go to the question's page (clicking the aptly named "link" link), and vote on it there.

Voting is a very important aspect of our peer review system, and although it's a good thing that `/review` focuses on the task at hand, there isn't any reason why you shouldn't vote on a post you discovered through any of review queues, if you honestly feel it deserves your (up/down) vote.

Comment: Shoot, I should've mentioned I knew about this option but was specifically wanting to ask about having the voting buttons "*closer*", e.g. available *on the review page*. This is a good option though if you feel strongly (strong enough to open the question in a new tab and vote) about voting of course.

Comment: @Jeroen See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141145/162704 - Short version is that Stack Exchange feels the focus should be at the task at hand, and voting, albeit important, is not part of the task at hand when reviewing close votes. It's still an option, obviously, but they don't want to make it _too_ easy. I guess what they are saying (in their own unique way) is that when you discover posts from the close vote queue you should only vote on them if you feel strongly enough to open the question in a new tab.

Comment: Ah, in that case my question *is* a duplicate. Darnit, and I searched so hard! Thx for your answer.