# Remove Upvote/Downvote Icons from Low Quality Queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, voting, low-quality-posts

In the Low Quality Posts queue the upvote/downvote icons are displayed but they don't respond to clicks. It has been pointed out in comments that it is by-design that we cannot vote in this queue, but the behaviour of these buttons is not consistent with the rest of the site.

[image]

I'd expect either for:

- the icons to not be there (as in Close/Reopen Votes)
- clicking the icons to show an error message (like when voting on your own post)

@TravisJ pointed out that these icons do show you if you have voted on the post previously. If this is the reason for their visibility then I suggest just adding some sort of error that informs the user that voting is disabled. A better message might be "Voting is disabled in this queue":

[image]

Comment: [By design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141145/152859): *A concern with allowing voting in the Low Quality queue specifically is that you're not viewing answers in the context of other answers, or a question in the context of its answers. You're never able to vote in these circumstances normally - it's worth remembering that voting directly from the list of questions was considered early on, and discarded as too likely to produce bad results*

Comment: Ah good find, still think it's odd that the buttons are visible and identical to their enabled alternatives

Comment: @Sha is right, but yeah - this is still a bug because when voting isn't available *the buttons are supposed to be hidden.*

Comment: Agreed, you can still change this post to feature request asking to hide the buttons there or at least show error message when clicking them to explain that it's not possible via the review.

Comment: Ok will do that

Comment: @9Shogsa-Shogging not really, I can see vote buttons next to my own posts and on locked posts, however in those cases we do get friendly message when clicking them.

Comment: @ShadowWizard What happened to your name ?

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname I changed it to try and get a hat, no hat, couldn't change back, had to reset. Sad.

Comment: Voting isn't disabled on your posts, @Sha. And locked posts are a bit weird, since the buttons are hidden for Historical Locked posts but not others.

Comment: The arrows should be grayed out if they are inactive

Comment: Just an FYI, but it should say "Don't WORK" in the screenshot...  "werk" is not a word.

Comment: @Charlie74 Most posts on SO contain a word that is "not a word" :/

Comment: @Charlie74, werk is a werd where I come from, I've switched the message to something more meaningful now anyway.

Comment: If in the past you had voted on the post, would your vote show in the form of one of the arrows being highlighted?

Comment: In the past, the arrows weren't shown, @Travis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry for that. Apparently copy-pasting code from StringBuilder code into razor cshtml views can go wrong every now and then.

Fixed in next build; watch out for rev `2013.12.23.1803` on meta and `2013.12.23.1263` on sites.

Comment: phew I was pretty certain something had changed, rarely ever go to the low quality queue atm though so wasn't sure.

Comment: Did you just admit to copying and pasting code?!

Comment: Finally spotted a LQP in the queue, thanks for the fix!