# Why Can't I Flag from the Low Quality Review Queue?

Tags: support, review, flags, spam

I just spotted a spam answer in the VLQ review queue on Travel. I wanted to flag but there was no link. So I clicked Delete and then used the history to get to the question and flagged it as spam. But why wasn't that an option in the Review?

Comment: Somewhat related From Shog9's answer: [*The core philosophy here is that each queue focuses on a specific task or question, and provides the tools most important for resolving it.*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141145/158100)

Comment: Related on Meta.SO: [What am I supposed to do with a piece of spam that I review in the low quality queue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274496)

Answer (score 1):

The LQP queue isn't there to handle spam.  People that see spam, or automated processes that detect spam, should be casting spam flags, not VLQ flags.  The LQP queue is there to handle posts with different types of problems than spam.  If you see a post in that queue (or any queue) that has a problem unrelated to the scope of the queue you're in then the proper course of action is to navigate to the post directly and handle it as appropriate.

Comment: I know that posts are not put in there for possibly being spam. But why, if I see that it is spam, do I need to follow a multi step process to handle it? Why **actively suppress** the flag link so that I can't do something natural?

Comment: @KateGregory Why use a review queue at all if you just want to have all of the options that you have when viewing the question normally?  The whole point of having review queues is so that they can do one thing really well, without distracting the user by trying to have them do everything all at once.  If you want to do other actions you can, you just need to leave the queue to do it.